# SVN Server config for not allow same message commit from client

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, svn-server

I had setup SVN Server for my group work. And now, I want user could not commit code to Server with the same messages. 
Is it possible to format comment from client like: `*.*.*.*` (1.0.0.1). If user commit with wrong format, they will be unable to commit. Is this possible to do on SVN Server?

E.x:

> User1 commit revision 1 with the message: `Version 1.0`
>
> User2 commit revision 2 with the same message: `Version 1.0` (This
>   will not be allowed)

Comment: precommit hook would likely work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ssnobody` is on the right track. You'll need to write some code to handle the logic in the `precommit`. We use something similar to ensure that the commits aren't empty. Doing duplicate entries sounds like something more that management/architects would have to enforce because nothing would stop the users from typing the same message or adding random characters to the end.

The following shows how precommit can be used to guard against empty commits https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928023/how-can-i-prevent-subversion-commits-without-comments